# Using the Open Graph to alter the text that is posted when clicking a "like" button

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

If I'm just altering what's written when a like button is pressed, do I need to set the extra scope permissions for the fb:like element on my site?

I'd rather not request more permissions since that decreases the number of users that would join my site with Facebook Connect. I also don't see why I would need to, since I'm not posting anything they wouldn't see otherwise (just altering the text so that the act of liking something makes more sense contextually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best resource for that would be facebooks permissions page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#open_graph_perms

Im not sure how your modifying whats written but you can do that through the open graph. In that case I think you just need the basic open graph permissions.

"Open Graph permissions allow your app to publish actions to the Open Graph and also to retrieve actions published by other applications. To request these permissions, you must enable the Enhanced Auth Dialog."

Hope that helps